# How do I create a Sequence in Pyspark that resets when rows change from 0 to 1 and and increments when all are 1's

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-notebook

I have a pyspark dataframe like this  and need the SEQ output as shown:

```
R_ID    ORDER   SC_ITEM seq
A   1       0
A   3   1   1
A   4   1   2
A   5   1   3
A   6   1   4
A   7   1   5
A   8   1   6
A   9   1   7
A   10  0   0
A   11  1   1
A   12  0   0
A   13  1   
A   14  0   
A   15  1   1
A   16  1   2
A   17  1   3
A   18  1   4
A   19  1   5
A   20  1   6
A   21  0   0
A   22  0   0
B   1   0   0
B   2   1   1
C   1   1   1
C   2   1   2
```

Not sure if the data is showing properly. So pic attached :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzURm.png)

I did something like this :

```py
RN = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))


.when(((F.col("R_ID")==(lag(F.col("R_ID"),1).over(RN))) & (F.col("SC_ITEM")== 1)), (F.col("SC_ITEM") + (lag(F.col("SEQ"),1).over(RN))))\
```

Not sure if I can do lead or lag over the SEQ. Please help how to do this

Comment: Why there are two blank `seq`?

Comment: Because thats how the data is and we have to treat is as 0

Comment: I thought SEQ is the output not input? can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant SC_ITEM can have blanks. For SEQ, i had not completed the output but you are right, it should continue as 1 0. Thank you in advance